# Ford Fiesta 2001 1.25 engine issue

Tags: engine, ford, warning-light, fiesta

ok got a problem bought an old 1.25 zetec fiesta all seemed to be ok with it

however - engine warning light is on after i got to work today, oil level was low (i never checked it to be honest) but its running ok no knocks etc, no misfire and oil level has been topped up.

How do I go about resetting the engine warning light? I have remvoed the negative lead and will put it back on for my journey home but not sure if this will work or not?

the car was stood for 8 weeks without use and is coming up for 15 years old so i expected some issue not right away!

Comment: UPDATE - Took the car to a garage this morning and was told it looks like a rogue message from the Lamba sensor and the CAT. I was told if the lamba sensor goes a bit daft the cat will as well. these have now both been cleared and I just need to drive it home to see if the light stays out!

Answer (score 2):

Disconnecting the battery of the vehicle will erase any stored engine codes (remove positive and negative cables and then wait for 15 minutes for residual charge to empty), but I would recommend getting the codes actually read at an auto service center or parts store. Typically these places will read the engine codes for free with an OBD-II diagnostic tool.

Since you described the vehicle as having no noticeable problems so far I would think that you'll be fine. However, if the engine light comes back on after you've cleared the codes then there is definitely a problem there that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Turn off the engine and close all the doors
2. Turn the key to electrical systems on (Position II)
3. Hold down the gas pedal and brake pedal simultaneously for over 20 seconds

This is, at least in some of Ford's smaller vehicles, a method that effectively resets the check engine light.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a code reader and it turns out my Catalist is failing! - thansk everyone for the assistance